# Trigger in SQL Server 2012

Tags: t-sql, triggers, sql-server-2012

My first post here, and a newbie in SQL Server

I have written a few triggers before, This one does not seems to work. Is it my nested select? I'm not getting any errors. Just nothing is e-mailed.

```
Use ABCTRAINING

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO



alter TRIGGER TAXPERCENT
   ON  [dbo].[AP101_VOUCHER_DISTR] AFTER update AS 



declare @VAT numeric(15,2),
@Total numeric(15,2),
@VATPERCENT numeric(15,2),
@Voucher nvarchar(max),
@AMT numeric(15,2),
@GL numeric(15,2)

Select @Voucher = i.ap101_voucher,
@AMT = i.ap101_amt,
@GL = i.AP101_GL_ACCT,
@VAT = (select sum(iif(@GL = '70102501110' or @GL = '70102501120',@AMT,0))),
@Total = (select sum(@AMT)),
@VATPERCENT = @VAT/(@Total-@VAT)
from inserted i


if @VATPERCENT <> 0.140

BEGIN
DECLARE @msg nvarchar(MAX)
Declare @Subj varchar(MAX)
Declare @EM nvarchar(MAX)
SET @msg = 'The VAT on this Voucher ' + @Voucher + ' ' + 'does not equal 14% ' + ' ' + @VATPERCENT
SET @Subj = 'Voucher Error'
set @EM = 'xxxxxx@company.co.za'

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
@importance ='High',
@recipients=@EM,
@body= @msg,
@subject = @Subj,
@body_format = 'HTML',  
@profile_name = 'ABC Profile'
END
```

Any help will be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: You're writing broken triggers. `inserted` (and `deleted`) can contain *multiple* rows (or no rows). You can't just assign column values to scalar variables (you're not even, strictly, guaranteed that multiple variables will all receives values from the same row)

Answer (score 0):

In the specific case, yes you're correct that the nested select will not work.

```
Select @Voucher = i.ap101_voucher,
@AMT = i.ap101_amt,
@GL = i.AP101_GL_ACCT,
@VAT = (select sum(iif(@GL = '70102501110' or @GL = '70102501120',@AMT,0))),
@Total = (select sum(@AMT)),
@VATPERCENT = @VAT/(@Total-@VAT)
from inserted i
```

At the point at which the nested select is executed, `@GL` and `@AMT` haven't been assigned values. All of the columns in a `SELECT` clause are (effectively/logically) computed in parallel.

As I said in a comment, you also need to treat `inserted` as a *table*. It can contain zero, one or *many* rows.

I can't as yet re-write this into a cleaner form since I'm unsure why you wrote the subselect in the first place and what it was intended to produce.

Comment: This script works fine when I run it in Man Studio. It gives just a sinle line.  Select ap101_voucher,
(select sum(case when AP101_GL_ACCT in ('70102501110', '70102501120') then ap101_amt else 0 end )) as Tax,
(sum(AP101_AMT)) as Total
into #temp
from inserted
group by AP101_VOUCHER

select ap101_voucher,
Total/(Total-Tax) as VATPERCENT
from #temp